# Does Windows 8 output different hdmi signal?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, mac, hdmi

So i bought this http://www.kanex.com/xd

Their old website used to advertise that it would work with a PC (in the Q&A section).

I bought it so that i could send my PC signal to my IMAC 27" late 2009 model, which was with their specs.

After trying multiple times without success, messing around with different resolution and all, the Target Display Mode would proc and apply, but nothing would show on the IMAC screen unfortunately.

So i contacted Kanex Support, and after 3 weeks of trying to get an answer from them, one of their tech finally gave me a response that it's because my PC runs windows 8, and that this OS sends a different HDMI signal.

There is the complete awnser

> So we ran several test on a Late 2009 iMac with different
>   laptops/desktops and have come to the conclusion that the reason your
>   laptop is not working with the XD is the fact its running on Windows
>   10. The Chipset inside of the XD  isn’t able to send the signal because the signal that is sent through the operating system for
>   Windows 10 is different

Later on during the email thread, the tech replied with this :

> Since our product was made in 2010, the chipset that was made with was
>   set for the only operating systems that were available at the time.
>   Since Windows 8 was release in 2012, Windows 8.1 would as well not be
>   supported through the XD

Question is : Do HDMI signal really change with the OS or is this awnser complete crap ?

Thanks all

Comment: How does this device connect to the iMac monitor?  Does it go to the iMac first, or directly to the monitor?

Comment: So it's a box, that supposedly transform the hdmi signal into minidisplay port signal. - You have a Hdmi port and a Minidisplay port. You plug hdmi in the PC and the MDP into the imac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this awnser complete crap ?

This answer is complete crap. The OS does not send a "different" HDMI signal.

You may be looking at newer revisions of HDMI (e.g. HDMI 2.0, 1.4, etc) but laptop outputs are backwards compatible, and furthermore these are functions of the graphics card and nothing to do with the OS.

Comment: So it should work, and have nothing to do with my computer ? The XD would be the component at fault here ?

Comment: To add on top of this, the driver was outputting different parameters (Scaling), which old win7 computers dindt have back in the days with the hardware. So the OS had nothing to do with this, it was more hardware related and how the drivers handle this.